# How can I match most specific to least specific records in SQL?

Tags: sql

Here is the back story.

I am trying to generate a list of transactions that includes the correct commission value for a specific person.  Not everyone is eligible for commission, but those who are have entries in a commission table that specifies what invoice item, item subclass, item class, and/or default  commission value they earn.

My problem is in the way the commission table is constructed that makes it very difficult to select on as shown below:

**COMMISSION Table**

```
staffid sequence invoiceitemid subclassid invclassid commission commtype 
------- -------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
KH      1        (null)        (null)     (null)     20.0       1        
KH      2        (null)        (null)     BOA        0.0        2        
KH      3        (null)        (null)     GRO        0.0        2        
KH      4        (null)        (null)     HEA        5.0        2        
KH      5        (null)        (null)     FTP        5.0        2        
KH      6        (null)        (null)     NTR        0.0        2        
KH      7        (null)        EUK        NTR        5.0        2        
KH      8        (null)        FOP        NTR        5.0        2        
KH      9        (null)        PUR        NTR        5.0        2        
KH      10       (null)        RC         NTR        5.0        2        
KH      11       (null)        (null)     MSC        0.0        2        
KH      12       (null)        (null)     MIS        0.0        2        
KH      13       1171          (null)     (null)     15.8       2        
KH      14       1173          (null)     (null)     15.2       2
```

Again, only one commission value should be selected per transaction based on the most specific to least specific columns in the COMMISSION table.

**Most Specific-** invoiceitemid, subclassid, invclassid -**Least Specific**

For example 1:
If the transaction included:

- invoiceitemid: 1234
- subclassid: FOP
- invclass: NTR

The SQL should match on the subclassid ("FOP") and not on the invclass ("NTR") resulting in a commission of 5.0 instead of 0.0

For example 2: 
If the transaction included no matches:

- invoiceitemid: 1234
- subclassid: STR
- invclass: BLA

The SQL should match on the invoiceitemid (null), subclassid (null), and invclass (null) resulting in a commission of 20.0

**What I've Tried**
Using COALESCE(invoiceitemid, subclassid, invclassid) to create a column with the most specific item in that record works.

However, in the first example, NTR occurs before FOP in the table, so it is incorrectly matched upon first. (See Below)

```
SELECT COALESCE(invoiceitemid, subclassid, invclassid) AS COMBINE, * 
FROM stcomm
WHERE staffid = 'KH'
ORDER BY sequence DESC

COMBINE staffid sequence invoiceitemid subclassid invclassid commission commtype 
------- ------- -------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
URN     KH      28       (null)        URN        MSC        0.0        2        
6326    KH      27       6326          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
6325    KH      26       6325          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
6324    KH      25       6324          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
6328    KH      24       6328          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
5671    KH      23       5671          (null)     (null)     20.0       2        
5793    KH      22       5793          (null)     (null)     20.0       2        
4263    KH      21       4263          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
5081    KH      20       5081          (null)     (null)     20.0       2        
3759    KH      19       3759          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
4846    KH      18       4846          (null)     (null)     0.0        2        
SUH     KH      17       (null)        SUH        SUP        5.0        2        
SUD     KH      16       (null)        SUD        SUP        5.0        2        
SUP     KH      15       (null)        (null)     SUP        0.0        2        
1173    KH      14       1173          (null)     (null)     15.2       2        
1171    KH      13       1171          (null)     (null)     15.8       2
```

To fix this issue, I ordered the sequence field in descending so the most specific "FOP" would be selected first.  This does work.

**How do I query the COMMISSION table to show the correct commission in my transaction?**

Here is my SQL for my transaction:

```
SELECT T.staffid, T.invoiceid, T.invoiceitemid, I.subclassid, I.classid, T.quantity, T.invoiceprice
FROM TRANSACT T, INVOITEM I
WHERE T.invoiceitemid = I.invoiceitemid
AND T.staffid = 'KH'

staffid invoiceid invoiceitemid subclassid classid quantity invoiceprice 
------- --------- ------------- ---------- ------- -------- ------------ 
KH      2555.0    04000         FOP        NTR     2.00     3.40         
KH      3575.0    04000         FOP        NTR     7.00     11.90        
KH      3981.0    04000         FOP        NTR     6.00     10.20        
KH      4333.0    04000         FOP        NTR     1.00     1.79         
KH      6401.0    04000         FOP        NTR     5.00     8.95         
KH      7863.0    04000         FOP        NTR     12.00    21.48
```

I have never encountered a table with such a strange design before with no primary key to select on.

For any assistance you guys can provide, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

One approach: link to each type of commission separately, and use a case clause to determine which is the most specific available - like so:

```
SELECT T.staffid, 
       T.invoiceid, 
       T.invoiceitemid, 
       I.subclassid, 
       I.classid, 
       T.quantity, 
       T.invoiceprice,
       case
           when iic.staffid is not null then iic.commission
           when scc.staffid is not null then scc.commission
           when icc.staffid is not null then icc.commission
           else def.commission
       end Applicable_Commission
FROM TRANSACT T
JOIN INVOITEM I ON T.invoiceitemid = I.invoiceitemid
LEFT JOIN stcomm iic /* Invoice Item Commission */
  ON T.staffid = iic.staffid and 
     T.invoiceitemid = iic.invoiceitemid
LEFT JOIN stcomm scc /* Sub Class Commission */
  ON T.staffid = scc.staffid and 
     T.subclassid = scc.subclassid and 
     T.invclassid = scc.invclassid
LEFT JOIN stcomm icc /* Inv Class Commission */
  ON T.staffid = icc.staffid and 
     T.invclassid = icc.invclassid and 
     icc.subclassid is null
LEFT JOIN stcomm def /* Default Commission */
  ON T.staffid = iic.staffid and 
     def.invclassid is null and 
     def.subclassid is null and 
     def.invoiceitemid is null
WHERE T.staffid = 'KH'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you want with a `left outer join` and aggregation:

```
select t.*
from (select t.invoiceid, t.invoiceitemid, t.classid, t.subclassId,
             t.quantity, t.invoiceprice, i.*
             min(i.sequence) over (partition by t.invoiceid, t.invoiceitemid) as minseq
      from TRANSACT t left outer join
           INVOITEM i
           on (t.staffid = i.staffid or i.staffid is NULL) and
              (t.invoiceitemid = i.invoiceitemid or i.invoiceitemid is null) and
              (t.classid = i.classid or i.classid is null) and
              (t.subclassid = i.subclassid or i.subclassid is null)
      where t.staffid = 'KH'
     ) t
where sequence = minseq or minseq is null
```

The `join` in the subquery should be getting all possible matches in the invoice list.  The window function calculates the minimum sequence number for the matches.  And then this is used to choose one row per item in the original data.